# How to get string before and after <br> tag using Python

Tags: python, html

I have a data crawler (BeautifulSoup) running which returns the following strings assigned to a variable `priceLast`:

```
<td>
200,90<br/>
196,90                          </td>
```

```
<td>
20,90<br/>
16,90                           </td>
```

```
<td>
2,90<br/>
1,90                            </td>
```

The spaces varies from time to time, hence I would like to assign the chars between `<td>XXXX<br/>` to var `price1` and those right after `<br/>` until the first space to var `price2`.

I tried `.split` to approach a solution

```
priceLast.split("<br/>")
```

but this throws:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the text from the `td` tag, and split at the new line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """
<td>
200,90<br/>
196,90                          </td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
prices = soup.find("td").text.strip().split("\n")
print(prices[0], prices[1])
#200,90 196,90
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get the numbers:

```
m = re.findall('\d+,\d+', str)
```

This will return the list of prices in the format 0,0(digits seperated with comma)

For example:

```
import re

str='<td> \
200,90<br/>\
196,90                          </td>'

m = re.findall('\d+,\d+', str)
print(m)
```

output:

```
['200,90', '196,90']
```

More information on regex: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `priceList` is not an object of string type?

I have tried it below and the `.split()` should work.

```
>>>string = "<td>\
... 200,90<br/>\
... 196,90                          </td>"
>>>new = string.split('<br/>')
>>>new
['<td>200,90', '196,90                          </td>']
```